# Python pandas: left join by key and value in list of values:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'D', 'F'],
                   'list_values': [[2, 4, 6], [4, 8], [1, 3, 5], [7, 9]]})
```

I need to  make a left join by :

1. `df1['key'] = df2['key']`
2. `df1['value'] in  df2['list_values']`

The output needs to be:

```
   key  value  list_values
0   A     1       Nan
1   B     2     [2, 4, 6]
2   C     3      Nan
3   D     4     [4, 8]
```

I can merge by key, but how I can add a second conditional?

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='key', right_on='key', how='left')
............ ??
```

Comment: I believe your output is incorrect, this should match `[4, 8]` for `D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra column in `df2` and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) it to act as a secondary key for the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = df1.merge(df2.assign(value=df2['list_values']).explode('value'),
                on=['key', 'value'], how='left')
```

Alternatively, `merge` and filter:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='left')
          .loc[lambda d: [not isinstance(l, list) or v in l
                          for v, l in zip(d['value'], d['list_values'])]]
       )
```

Output:

```
  key value list_values
0   A     1         NaN
1   B     2   [2, 4, 6]
2   C     3         NaN
3   D     4      [4, 8]
```

Comment: @R.Baraiya I believe OP's output is incorrect, the described logic is "*df1['value'] in df2['list_values']*"

Answer (score 1):

You can even just tried to insert column **by checking list_values for each key's using lambda.**

Code :

```
df1['list_values'] = df1.apply(lambda r: sum([l for l in list(df2.loc[df2['key']==r.key].list_values) if r.value in l] ,[]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
key value   list_values
0   A   1   []
1   B   2   [2, 4, 6]
2   C   3   []
3   D   4   [4, 8]
```

Comment: I doesn't seem to work, and even if it did it wouldn't check that `value` is in `list_values`, you just take the last match

Comment: Thnks @mozway, Updated